# Using HTML Placeholder with class in Laravel 4

Tags: html, laravel

While using HTML Placeholder with class in Laravel 4, shows me this error.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

I've used

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your Name') }}
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close your parentheses `()` for `Form::text()` .

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Your Name')) }}
```